# Как создать или запустить такое окно через html

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Прошу помощи запустить такое окно через html или css(я новичок)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%8B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете узнать больше информации о возможных "префиксах", в ссылке тега `<a>` [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

```html
<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Отправить писмо</a>
```